# Linux get the size of a folder and its subfolders to a certain depth

Tags: linux, size, directory, subdirectory

In Linux, I have the following folder structure, I want to get the size of the folder and its subfolders to a certain depth.

I have this structure:

```
/AAAA/BBBB/1111
/AAAA/BBBB/2222
/AAAA/BBBB
/AAAA/CCCC
/AAAA/DDDD/3333
/AAAA/DDDD
/AAAA
```

`du -m`, shows me the entire tree, not just 2 levels as I need.  What is the proper command?

Comment: Get the total size of a folder and subfolders/subfiles: `du -s /home/el`  returns a number.  add the -h flag to make it human readable.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You want the `-d` or `--max-depth` option.

```
du -d 2
```

Comment: Thank you, I have looked in the man page, but to my shame I was in a hurry and I missed that.

Answer (score 3):

Limit the depth of search `--max-depth=N`.

Comment: sorry, didn't realise it had been answered.